# PDO query fails to execute when AUTO_INCREMENT included in creation script, but query seems to be valid

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get some test scripts set up with PHPUnit using in-memory databases, but I'm having trouble creating the databases correctly. When I first ran the queries it was running fine, but I'd forgotten to add AUTO_INCREMENT to the id field. Once I added that, PDO would drop out with a fatal error any time the script ran. I've tried running the same query through phpMyAdmin to see if it works (it goes through without any complaints) and even used that to perform the action I wanted and copied the SQL it ran without any luck, so I'm kind of at a loss for what's going on. If anyone can give me a hand with this it'd be a big help. Query can be found below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `checks` (
    `id` int(60) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `check_type` varchar(255),
    `purchase_id` varchar(255),
    `price` varchar(255),
    `time` varchar(255),
    `user_id` varchar(255),
    `email` varchar(255),
    `site_id` varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

VARCHAR's used for everything except ID because those are running through an automated script and the data type can vary. It's a MySQL database if that makes a difference. Thanks for any help you can give

edit: Adding the full error message as requested:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error

Comment: I tested that CREATE TABLE through PDO against MySQL 5.5.30.  It works fine.  You should edit your question and include the full error message, if any.

Comment: Will do, although it's just a generic syntax error message

Comment: I don't get that error in my test, either running the query ad hoc in  the mysql client, or when running via PDO.  Have you tried removing the AUTO_INCREMENT=1 table option in the last line, since that's redundant anyway?  I.e. a new CREATE TABLE sets the auto increment to 1 by default.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  I can try testing on the same version.  Find out:  `SELECT VERSION()` or `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version'`.

Comment: Two points.1/  In-memory databases should  you not be using SQLite?2/  Should you be creating tables in PHPUnit?

Comment: Bingo, we have a winner. I forgot that the test database stored in memory was using sqlite rather than mysql like the real database used by the system. Thanks David

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same thing when I switched to using PDO.  Remove the NOT NULL on the id field.  I don't know why... don't see any documentation.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `checks` (
    `id` int(60) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `check_type` varchar(255),
    `purchase_id` varchar(255),
    `price` varchar(255),
    `time` varchar(255),
    `user_id` varchar(255),
    `email` varchar(255),
    `site_id` varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```